# Image cutoff issue on next page while generating html to pdf in angulal using jspdf

Tags: image, jspdf

I am facing some issue like image cutoff issue while generating html to pdf in angular using jspdf library

[image]

```
onpdfExport() { 
    const doc = new jspdf("p", "pt", "a4");
    const source: any = document.getElementById("content-to-export")?.innerHTML;
    doc.html(source, {
      margin: [40, 0, 40, 0],
      autoPaging:'text',
      x: 0,
      y: 0,
      callback: function(pdf) {
        setTimeout(() => {
          doc.output("dataurlnewwindow");
        }, 500); 
      },
    },);
```